# How do I host a website that contains PUG templates in a sub-folder instead of an index.html file in the root directory of the project folder?

Tags: html, web, pug, hosting

I want to host my website for free but my files are in PUG and not HTML. From what I know, I need to have an index.html file that too in the root directory to be able to host the website since that index.html has the code for the landing page. I would compile them in HTML and then use those for the website but there are a lot of other files to be changed completely for the project. For example, the server code is written in Express.js which uses the PUG files not HTML. And the code for that would need to completely be changed for me to be able to use HTML files for hosting. Is there a simpler solution to this? I would like to get a link to a helpful resource that explains this or step-by-step instructions on how to accomplish this. Fingers crossed, there exists a solution.

I have looked everywhere online and in all of them they ask to compile to HTML but nowhere does it say what to do with the other files that use those PUG files and I haven't found any resource or tool for hosting the websites with the PUG files as they are.

Comment: It's not super clear what you're asking. A Pug site using Express doesn't have to have a static `index.html` in the root directory if there's a properly configured route for that instead. Express running on a Node server with Pug as the view engine doesn't need any static HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Express.js server its possible to set it up to render .pug files and send .html to user.

if you had index.pug template in ./views folder

add following to server.js

```
   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views/'); // template file location
   app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // set template engine
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
       res.render('index', { title: 'Hey' });
   });
```

and do same for other routes

```
   app.get('route', (req, res) => {
       res.render('pug_template_name', { object: 'with key: value pairs for template'});
   });
```